# Slick slider проблема с фото

Tags: php

у меня проблема со слайдером
через несколько прокрутов слайдера последние или 2 последних фото прогружается
Помогите кто знает
[image: Вот этот момент]

```js
  $(".slick-slider").slick({
      infinite: true,
      slidesToShow: 3,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      speed: 1000,
      dots: false,
    });
```

```html
@php
  $title = get_field("title");
  $slider = get_field("slider");
  $columns = get_field("columns");
  $link = get_field("link");
  $totalColumns = count($columns);
@endphp


<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="content-section-10 mt-20 py-20">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">
        <h2>{!! $title !!}</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-row flex flex-wrap mt-20">
          @if ($slider)
            <div class="slick-slider">
              @foreach ($slider as $image)
                 {!! App\get_retina_lazy_image($image, 'thumb-700') !!}
              @endforeach
            </div>
           @endif
      </div>
      <div class="columns mt-32">
        <div class="city-row flex flex-wrap -mx-4">
          @if (have_rows("columns"))
            @php
              $count = 0;
            @endphp
            @while (have_rows("columns"))
              @php
                the_row();
                $logo = get_sub_field("logo");
                $title = get_sub_field("title");
                $description = get_sub_field("description");
                $open_info = get_sub_field("open_info");
                $count++;
              @endphp
              <div class="city-col px-4 w-1/3 {{ $count > ($totalColumns - 3) ? 'mb-0' : 'mb-18' }}">
                <div class="content-col flex flex-col items-center">
                  <div class="logo">
                    @if ($logo)
                      {!! App\get_retina_lazy_image($logo, 'thumb-400') !!}
                    @endif
                  </div>
                  <div class="title-col mt-4">
                    <h5>{!! $title !!}</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="description mt-2">
                    <p>{!! $description !!}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="open-info mt-2">
                    <p class="par-14 text-primary font-medium">{!! $open_info !!}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            @endwhile
          @endif
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="link">
        @if ($link)
          {!! App\get_button($link, 'btn btn--primary--sm') !!}
        @endif
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```